# Angular2 - http.get not calling the webpi

Tags: angular, get, fiddler

I don't know why this command runs properly but I can't find any log of calls in Fiddler...

```
let z = this.http.get('http://localhost:51158/api/User/TestIT?idUser=0')
```

The code pass into this step but If I try to catch all the http request using fiddler, I can't find any call...

Do you have idea on what is happening ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To initiate a request and receive a response you can add `map()` and `.catch()` to return an [Observable](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html) response from your method.

**Example Service:**

```
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
...

getMyData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:51158/api/User/TestIT?idUser=0')
        .map((res: Response) => {
           console.log(res); 
           return res;
         })
         .catch((err) => { 
            // TODO: Error handling
            console.log(err); 
            return err;
     }
}
```

Then subscribe to the Observable-returning method to execute the request:

**Example Subscription**

```
...

this.getMyData()
        .subscribe((res: any) => {
            console.log(res);
        },
        error => {
            // TODO: Error handling
            console.log(error);
        });
```

For a good starter example you can refer to the [Angular *Tour of Heroes* Example](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#fetch-data-with-_http-get-_)

**Note:** Untested code